How to enter only values of array into file in power automate
I'm sending three variables into my power automate flow, all arrays. I'm individually putting each one into its own Create CSV table component and their output is similar to this format:
[
{
"AMDTitle": "AMDrive",
"MiddayTitle": "Midday",
"EveningTitle": "Evenings"
}
]
Then I add all three Create CSV table outputs to a Sharepoint Create file component to make a csv file. The flow overall is doing what I want but it's putting even the keys into a row in the file like this:
row 1: AMDTitle MiddayTitle EveningTitle
row 2: AMDrive  Midday      Evenings
How can I get the array values only (row 2) and not both the key and values in the file?

can you double check it, please? I recreated your flow (if I got it not wrong), but the outcome is working as expected.

update: "Create CSV table action" with custom headers:


thanks for recreating it! Yes this is essentially what I'm doing and the outcome is the same, I'm wondering if there's a way to not have that first line (AMDTitle, MiddayTitle, EveningTitle) in the file though. I just want the second line alone.

okay, now I see it. :) The key is, that in the 'Create CSV table' action you should not choose 'Custom' instead of 'Automatic' in the 'Columns' section. Here you can skip the headers and get only the values via the Expression tab. These values should be:
`item()['EveningTitle']`
`item()['AMDTitle']`
`item()['MiddayTitle']`


I've added a new picture to the original answer showing the 'Create CSV table' action with custom headers.

You need to do the following changes to your Create CSV Table:

Change the Columns type from Automatic to Custom
Then for each column you only need to specify the value, you don't need to specify the column header. E.g. if your column name is Title 2 then you can get the value by using this formula: item()['Title 2']

Following is an example:

This will generate your desired output, i.e. without header, only values:

